# How do I grep a exact string from multiple files at the same time

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have multiple files(text file) in a folder like below where the 1st file contains some paths as a string and the other with path+file_name.

File1:

```
[root@centos7 test]# pwd
/root/test
[root@centos7 test]# cat file1.txt
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err
/abc/bce/34563/input
/abc/bce/34563/input/part1
/abc/bce/34563/input/part3/wrk
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/err
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/part3
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/part3/err
[root@centos7 test]#
```

File2:

```
[root@centos7 test]# pwd
/root/test/test
[root@centos7 test]# cat file2.txt
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9923.txt--20210315--
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR9950.txt--20200512--
[root@centos7 test]#
```

File3:

```
[root@centos7 test]# pwd
/root/test/test
[root@centos7 test]# cat file3.txt
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR1034.txt--20210110--
/abc/bce/34563/input/part1/AIR3426.txt--20200420--
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/part3/err/V.AIR7650.txt--20170625--
[root@centos7 test]#
```

Present output:

```
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9923.txt--20210315--
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR9950.txt--20200512--
test/file3.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR1034.txt--20210110--
```

Expected Output:

```
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9923.txt--20210315--
```

I am using `grep -rHw "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" test/` to match the line from file1 and extract their info from file2,file3,.... so on. However the problem lies,
when I tried to retrieve the line it takes all the similar lines from file2,file3, and so on. I don't know how I can do that when file1 is being compared with multiple files in a continuous manner.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, in your example you want to find lines in `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` that (a) contain the string "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" + an added string (the filenames), but (b) *don't* contain the other "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/**err**" string. As far as I can tell, what you want isn't possible, at least not in a single `grep` command.

The reason is that you simultaneously *do* want `grep` to find a longer string based on the search term (i.e., "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" matching "test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--"), and *don't* want `grep` to find a longer string based on the search term (i.e., "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" matching "test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/**err**/AIR9950.txt--20200512---").

For the specific example you gave, you could do `grep -rHw "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" test/ | grep -v "/err"`, but obviously that's not a generalised solution for all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion. you are right, I only need the line which is string+file_name() like `test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--` .Is there any other way to get this done through the `shell script`?